# convert sql to ling group by and average between 2 dates when end date can be null

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How to properly convert SQL to linq C#? I need to find the date diff and average assuming that end date can be null. Thank you.

```
SELECT
        dbo.Users.UserName, year(dbo.Eml.CreatedOn) as YEAR, month(dbo.Eml.CreatedOn) as MONTH,             
        Avg(DATEDIFF(day, dbo.Eml.CreatedOn, dbo.Eml.AssignedDate)) as D2AssignAverage,
        Avg(DATEDIFF(day, dbo.Eml.CreatedOn, dbo.Eml.SolvedDate)) as D2SoveAverage,
        Avg(DATEDIFF(day, dbo.Eml.CreatedOn, dbo.Eml.ClosedDate)) as D2CloseAverage


        from dbo.Eml

        FULL OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Users  ON dbo.Eml.AA.Id = dbo.Users.Id

        GROUP BY dbo.Users.UserName, month(dbo.Eml.CreatedOn), year(dbo.Eml.CreatedOn)
```

Edit:

Come up with this solution in case anyone encounters the same question:

```
    var q = (from emls in eml
                 join usr in users on emls.AAId equals usr.Id
                 group  emls 
                 by new { usr.UserName, year = emls.CreatedOn.Value.Year, month = emls.CreatedOn.Value.Month }  into grp

        select new AveragesViewModel
                 {
                     UserName = grp.Key.UserName,
                     Year = grp.Key.year,
                     Month = grp.Key.month,
                     AD2Assign = (long)grp.Average(h => DbFunctions.DiffDays(h.CreatedOn, h.AssignedDate )),
                     AD2Solve =  (long)grp.Average(h => DbFunctions.DiffDays(h.CreatedOn, h.SolvedDate)),
                     AD2Close =  (long)grp.Average(h => DbFunctions.DiffDays(h.CreatedOn, h.ClosedDate))

        });

        return View(q);
```

Comment: I don't think anyone is just going to do the work for you.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not trying to be rude. When asking a question on SO it's good practice to post the effort you have taken to solve your problem as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not using LINQ to Entities but just LINQ to SQL,

For translating SQL to LINQ,

1. Translate subselects as separately declared variables.
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, leaving monadic operators (`DISTINCT`, `TOP`, etc) as functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (`new { }`) for multiple columns
5. Left Join is simulated by using a `into join_variable` and doing another `from` from the join variable followed by `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.
6. Replace `COALESCE` with the conditional operator and a null test.
7. `SELECT *` must be replaced with `select range_variable` or for joins, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.
8. `SELECT fields` must be replaced with `select new { ... }` creating an anonymous object with all the desired fields or expressions.

Note: There is no query comprehension equivalent to `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but you can use the following extension methods to do a lambda version:

```
private static Expression<Func<TP, TC, TResult>> CastSMBody<TP, TC, TResult>(LambdaExpression ex, TP unusedP, TC unusedC, TResult unusedRes) => (Expression<Func<TP, TC, TResult>>)ex;

public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
    IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) where TLeft : class where TRight : class where TResult : class {

    // (lrg,r) => resultSelector(lrg.left, r)
    var sampleAnonLR = new { left = (TLeft)null, rightg = (IEnumerable<TRight>)null };
    var parmP = Expression.Parameter(sampleAnonLR.GetType(), "lrg");
    var parmC = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TRight), "r");
    var argLeft = Expression.PropertyOrField(parmP, "left");
    var newleftrs = CastSMBody(Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(resultSelector, argLeft, parmC), parmP, parmC), sampleAnonLR, (TRight)null, (TResult)null);

    return leftItems.AsQueryable().GroupJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, (left, rightg) => new { left, rightg }).SelectMany(r => r.rightg.DefaultIfEmpty(), newleftrs);
}

private static Expression<Func<TParm, TResult>> CastSBody<TParm, TResult>(LambdaExpression ex, TParm unusedP, TResult unusedRes) => (Expression<Func<TParm, TResult>>)ex;

public static IQueryable<TResult> RightAntiSemiJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
    IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) where TLeft : class where TRight : class where TResult : class {

    // lgr => resultSelector((TLeft)null, lgr.right)
    var sampleAnonLgR = new { leftg = (IEnumerable<TLeft>)null, right = (TRight)null };
    var parmLgR = Expression.Parameter(sampleAnonLgR.GetType(), "lgr");
    var argLeft = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(TLeft));
    var argRight = Expression.PropertyOrField(parmLgR, "right");
    var newrightrs = CastSBody(Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(resultSelector, argLeft, argRight), parmLgR), sampleAnonLgR, (TResult)null);

    return rightItems.GroupJoin(leftItems, rightKeySelector, leftKeySelector, (right, leftg) => new { leftg, right }).Where(lgr => !lgr.leftg.Any()).Select(newrightrs);
}

public static IQueryable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
    IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) where TLeft : class where TRight : class where TResult : class {

    return leftItems.LeftOuterJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector).Concat(leftItems.RightAntiSemiJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector));
}
```

Comment: Updated to add lambda `FullOuterJoin`

Comment: perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @nanda I don't think your coworkers would be happy with such an query. Maintaining this code will be a challenge to say the list. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. Create a view and map to it.

Comment: @nanda - my fault - didn't mean the comment for you. deleted it.

Comment: @nanda you then. Do you really think you can maintain this, or even make sense of this? You are abusing LINQ in this case. Create a view and map to the view

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Justify "abusing LINQ". LINQ provides a type safe database query functionality but doesn't implement full outer join. This provides a type safe full outer join that produces optimal SQL. C#'s implementation (including LINQ) provides for programmer and library extensibility as a fundamental part of the language.

Comment: No it doesn't. It provides an *abstaction on top of other providers*. For databases, it's on top of *ORMs*. If you have to do joins in LINQ it means your mapping is bad and you didn't include the *relations*. As with all ORMs, it works with *entities* not tables and is *not* suitable for *reporting* queries - there are no entities with business behaviour in reporting, just data. This case is 100% reporting, with missing relations that force the use of joins.

Comment: The SQL queries generated by LINQ are suboptimal, a well known fact and a source of a LOT of questions in SO. They are not provided by C#, but each separate ORM. Linq2SQL was only meant as a demo. It has well known leaks too, like executing in memory operations that it can't translate to SQL without warnings. That's why EF is used instead of L2S and why *Dapper* is a lot faster than L2ES or EF

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So you can't report if you use ORMs? No wonder real work is done with LINQ to SQL.